# Error storage/unknown uploading picture to Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, react-native-firebase

Faced this error while working on a new React-Native project and using React-Native-Firebase library. Followed all tutorial setup steps and got this error. It's likely that this error can be faced in not react-native projects as well.

Answer (score 6):

I've spent so many hours trying to fix it and didn't find a solution to my problem on stackoverflow.

Turns out, the solution was as simple as going to Firebase Console => Storage => click Getting started which creates default Storage rules.

It was a new project and no storage rules existed.

Solution was found by running
`adb logcat` command, output showed something like 
`check security rules for firebase storage` and 
`no permission for storage`

Hope this will save you hours debugging I wasted!

Comment: That was exactly my problem too, I am glad I found your post as it saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I had a wrong storage bucket URL set up (`something.firebaseapp.com`) when it should have been `something.appspot.com`

Answer (score 0):

Just make the rules of your firebase storage to be true i.e. allow read and write to be true. That will do the trick. Like this

```
rules version = '2';
 service firebase.storage {
   match /b/{bucket}/o {
   match /{allPaths=**} {
    allow read, write: if true;
  }
 }
}
```